# Why does Bradbury use "had to" in "what they had to offer."?

Tags: wording-choice, ray-bradbury

An excerpt from "Just this Side of Byzantium" by Ray Bradbury:

> I had to send myself back, with words as catalysts, to open the memories out and see what they **had to**
> offer.

Why does the author use the auxiliary word "had to" here, making me feel the action "offer" is compulsory? I think it'd be better to leave out "had to."

Comment: You're parsing it wrong (not surprising, since the grammar is ambiguous). It's not "what they (had to) offer", it's "(what they had) (to offer)." That is, the main verb is *had*, and *to offer* is an infinitive that follows it.  What it means is: *what they contained and could offer.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Had' is not used in the same sense in 'had to offer' as it is in 'had to send'.

In 'had to send' 'had' denotes, as you observe, a sense of compulsion. In 'had to offer' it denotes possession.

To paraphrase; the speaker feels compelled to send himself back, with words as catalysts, to open the memories out and see what they have, that they can offer.